# reflect a 2D vector over another vector without using normal, why this gives the wrong result?

Tags: vectors, reflection

I'd like to reflect vector $\mathbf{v_1}$ relative to the line through the origin defined by $\mathbf{v_2}$ *without calculating the normal to $\mathbf{v_2}$ first.*

For example if my mirror is along the x axis so that $v_2$ is $(2, 0)$, and the original vector $\mathbf{v_1}$ is $(1, -1)$, I expect the reflected vector to be $(1, +1)$

The equation given in Wikiepdia's [Reflection (mathematics); Reflection across a line in the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)#Reflection_across_a_line_in_the_plane) is

$$\mathbf{v_{refl}} = \mathbf{v_1} - 2 \frac{\mathbf{v_1} \cdot \mathbf{v_2}}{\mathbf{v_2} \cdot \mathbf{v_2}}\mathbf{v_2}$$

However I get $(-1, -1)$ as if it were reflected by the y axis; the *normal* to my plane.

Am I misunderstanding how this equation should be used? Is there a different expression that gives me the reflection without calculating the normal first explicitly?

[image]

Comment: The formula is incorrect; the one immediately after is correct. Note that $2\operatorname{proj}_l(v)$ is the *second* term in the formula you have.

Comment: @Rahul bingo! Thank you very much; I should have seen that. Yes that works nicely. Would you like to write up a quick answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the general situation:
[image: General Situation]

It all boils down to [vector addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction), [scalar multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication) and [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection).

We're given $\vec{v_1}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec{v_2}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. We're asked to calculate $v_{\text{refl}}$.

$\large{k = \frac{\vec{v_1}\cdot\vec{v_2}}{\vec{v_2}\cdot\vec{v_2}} = \frac{\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1 \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}}{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0 \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}}} =1$

and

$\begin{align*}\color{green}{v_{\text{refl}}} &= \color{red}{- v_1}+\color{orange}{2kv_2}  \\&= -v_1+2v_2 &&, k=1  \\&= -\begin{bmatrix} 1\\-1\end{bmatrix}+2\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix} \\&= \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix} \end{align*}  $

So, yes, the formula from wikipedia $v_{\text{refl}}=v_1 - 2kv_2$ is not $100\%$ correct. To get the right result, multiply the result $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$, that you've got using the formula from wikipedia, by $-1$, because the right formula is $v_{\text{refl}}=-v_1 + 2kv_2$.

Comment: Oh this is very useful as well as helpful, thank you for taking the time to break it down into bite-sized chunks! Also, congratulations on your "association bonus"! Somehow my accept triggered a retroactive +100 on several sites for you. I knew that this happens theoretically, but I've never seen it happen in real time before. yay!

Comment: I don't get this with "retroactive +100 on several sites", but you're welcome!

Comment: Your reputation in Stack Overflow and Meta SE increase from 1 to 101 yesterday. And from now on, whenever you join any new SE site, your score will start out at 101 instead of 1.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of relying on found or memorized formulas, try to work this out for yourself from the fundamentals. The basic idea is that the vector $\mathbf v$ to be reflected is decomposed as $\mathbf v_\parallel+\mathbf v_\perp$, its respective components parallel to and perpendicular to the reflector. The reflection is then accomplished by reversing the perpendicular component, i.e., it is $\mathbf v_\parallel-\mathbf v_\perp$. Either of these components can be found via orthogonal projection; the other is then simply the difference between it and the original vector. Thus, the reflection of $\mathbf v$ can be expressed as either $$\mathbf v_\parallel - (\mathbf v - \mathbf v_\parallel) = 2\mathbf v_\parallel-\mathbf v$$ or $$(\mathbf v-\mathbf v_\perp)-\mathbf v_\perp = \mathbf v-2\mathbf v_\perp.$$ In your question, the reflector is spanned by $\mathbf v_2$, so you can compute $\mathbf v_\parallel$ directly via orthogonal projection onto $\mathbf v_2$ and then use the first form. When the reflector is a hyperplane for which you know the normal, then the second form is more convenient since you only have to project onto that normal to find $\mathbf v_\perp$.

Comment: Being able to regenerate an expression on demand is definitely the best way to own it. Thank you, It looks like I can learn how to to *orthogonal projection* in slides 15-17 [here](http://speech.ee.ntu.edu.tw/~tlkagk/courses/LA_2018/Lecture/orthogonal%20projection%20(v2).pdf) for example.

Comment: @uhoh Drilling down into that, you can always regenerate the formula for orthogonal projection onto a vector by remembering that for a _unit_ vector $\mathbf u$, the dot product with $\mathbf u$ gives the length of the projection onto $\mathbf u$ and its direction relative to $\mathbf u$.

Comment: doh! yes that's right. It's early here and I haven't had my coffee yet.